# data import from excel facing an issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am importing data from MS Excel.
The code i have written is,

```
var ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" +
    uploadfile.PostedFile.FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

objConn.Open();
try
{
    var objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", objConn);
}
```

and so on.

I got an error which looks very generic to me

**The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly**

*

> My worksheet name is spelled correclty 
>   but for my confirmation, i did below code
>   dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

```
if(dt == null)
{
  return null;
}

var excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;

// Add the sheet name to the string array.
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
  i++;
}
```

*
but i got my Data Table null.
My question is the connection is open successfully but i can't read data from the excel file.
**Is there any special Authentication required.?**
because i am getting the above error.

Comment: datasource is the name of the database and not the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Instead if Ace.OLEDB you may try by Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB, because I faced the simillar then I switch over to Jet.OLEDB

```
    string MyExelFile = "C:\Temp\Sample.xls";
    string MyExcelSheet = "[Sheet1$]";
    string StrConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + MyExelFile + ";

    Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1\"";
    String MySQLSelect = "select * from " + MyExcelSheet + "";
    DataTable Items=new DataTable() ;
```

`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection Cn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
Cn.ConnectionString = StrConn;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter Da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
(MySQLSelect, Cn);
Cn.Open();
   Da.Fill(Items);
Cn.Close();
</pre>`